# Intellij: Highlight current block of code

Tags: intellij-idea, highlighting

I was wondering if it is possible to highlight the block of code you are working on in Intellij Idea.

There was a similar question here: [Is there a way to highlight the currently active code block in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943929/is-there-a-way-to-highlight-the-currently-active-code-block-in-visual-studio-201#new-answer?newreg=89232d5495d14468ac145e0dc4d870fa) .

So what I mean is that if you have clicked into e.g. a method or a while loop... ,the background of the whole block becomes a bit lighter or whatever.

Comment: I posted my answer in this one, I am using intellij IDEA 2020.2.1 version.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678327/intellij-idea-highlight-vertical-indent-line-when-a-brace-is-matched/70576267#70576267

Answer (score 11):

There's already one such feature, but it's more subtle, in the form of a vertical line inside the left gutter... I can't recall whether it's enabled by default or not, but you can activate it by `File -> Settings -> Editor -> General`, scroll to the `Highlight on Caret Movement` section (about half of the page).

I looked around for a while but I have not yet found a way to change its appearance to match your description, although I personally prefer this *less intrusive* highlight than having all the background changed.

[image: Scope highlighting in action]

---

**P.S.** Not sure this is relevant or useful to you, but there was a plugin I tried a while ago called [CodeGlance](https://github.com/Vektah/CodeGlance) which offered a scrollable-map of the class:

[image: class map]

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's basically what I meant, but it's still not perfect. I'd like to have something you see instantly. Especially on my hiRes screen the line is verry thin.

Comment: @maxobermeier No problem, although like I said, so far I have not found a way to customise its appearance, so good luck with that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when this feature was implemented.  As of 2021, if you double click anywhere in the scope ( but not on text ), Intellij selects the current block of code ( text within two curly braces ).