# Intellij Idea - Highlight vertical indent line when a brace is matched

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there a default option or maybe a plugin to highlight the vertical indent line when a brace is matched like in this example ?
[image]
To make this screenshot I positioned two cursors: one on brace and one on indent line.

Comment: I haven't found a way of doing that, but there's a `Highlight current scope` option which is somewhat similar, but on the right gutter. Take a look at this [answer's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185597/intellij-highlight-current-block-of-code/38187336#38187336) GIF for a visual demo

Comment: Not bad but i think it will be difficult to see the blocks that are too far from that highlighted vertical line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it is set in here Preferences->Editor->Color Scheme-> Guides-> Indent guide selected->Background
[image]

After setting, now it will highlight as it looks
[image]