# IntelliJ IDEA - how to modify the default thickness of the indent guide? (picture)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to edit the thickness of this line which is always shown for scopes. Does somebody know if it can be achieved somehow? Thank you very much

[image]

PS: somewhat similar question: [Intellij: Highlight current block of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185597/intellij-highlight-current-block-of-code)

Answer (score 2):

See **Indent guide selected** under **Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General**:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, about the thickness do you have any idea? I mean to make the line much much thicker / wider so it is easier to see.

Comment: Only a custom theme seems to be an option: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes-customize.html#customizing-ui-controls