# Can I view only a specific part of code and make the rest disappear?

Tags: intellij-idea, focus

I'm using IntelliJ and VSCode and i'm wondering if there is a way to mark a part of the code and the tool will only display and focus on that code and will make the rest disappear. This will help to get rid of clutter code that i'm not interested in.

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185597/intellij-highlight-current-block-of-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can point the cursor over the code block you want to focus on, press `Ctrl+Shift+NumPad -` to collapse all code blocks and press `Ctrl+NumPad -` to expand the selected one. See [Write and edit source code | Code Folding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html?keymap=primary_windows#code_folding) for more information.

In addition you can consider using [Distraction Free Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ide-viewing-modes.html).